# What's the difference between 'unlink' and 'remove' from collection?

Tags: collections

[image]

I did 'unlink' and 'remove' respectively, but really don't know how the two are different. What's the difference between them?

Comment: edit: yes my bad, it looks like it works like an unlink, I guess some things need to be harmonized between 3D view commands and Outliner commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object is linked to more than one collection *Object > Collection > Remove From Collection* will give you the option to remove it from all collections or from one specific collection. *Unlink* in the outliner on the other hand only removes the selected object link from the collection it is in. If the object is linked to other collections, these will remain.

Comment: So you re saying that the two are the same except 'remove' give me more options ?

Comment: @나미손 Yes, if your selection in the outliner is also an object, they both result in a call to `BKE_collection_object_remove` in Blender's code.

Comment: thank you for nice answer.